# C++ iterator operator definition

Tags: c++, iterator, overloading, operator-keyword

any idea or link concerning the "definition" of how operators of iterators have to work? To be more exact: How excatly do, for instance, operators "==" and "!=" have to be implemented -- do they have to compare members of the data they hold (which imho would be a problem, as the iterator should not know about the data in the first place)? How do you compare to .end() and .start()? For pointer iterators: is it just an address check?

Would be glad to hear about your ideas or get a link to the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original STL has a [design document on iterators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html).

In short, they are a generalization of pointers, so `==` should check whether two iterators point at the same item in the same container. Pointer iterators should indeed compare equal when their pointers do.

Comparing to a `begin()` or `rbegin()` should be trivial; comparing to an `end()` or `rend()` can be done in various ways, like making it an index equal to the `size()` of a container.

Comment: That was what I hoped for, see above. Thaks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to read something like this: http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/iterators.html

The operators `==` and `!=` compare the iterators, not the data they refer to.

Comment: Great, that is what I hoped for and what I was expecting. Thanks for the link. I was in a quarrel with a colleague who implemented his own Iterator nested class and compared the data, which lead to sever problems when comparing to .end() or alike.

Answer (score 0):

The == and != operators aren't expected to compare the contents, they merely check whether two iterators refer to the same object.